# Eloquent: get changed columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I need to log updated columns using Eloquent `getChanges`, It works just fine when use it in the same code context right after ex: `updateOrCreate`, but when call it from the "provider" it returns empty array, example of boot in service provider:

```
   public function boot()
    {
        User::updating(function ($user) {
            dd($user->getChanges()); //empty array 
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the problem I should use `User::updated` instead, ex:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::updated(function ($user) {
        dd($user->getChanges());
    });
}
```